# How do I get random number between -20 and 20 with 3 decimals using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, random, decimal

I would liket to use javaScript to generate random number with 3 decimals.
using the following code:
${__javaScript((Math.random() * (40) - 20).toFixed(3) * 1,)}

it generate the value -7.829999999999999, but I want the value -7.830.

Anyone knows how do I get what I want? thank you in advance.
enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77bg7.png)

Comment: I tried your code, it seems you are doing it the correct way. You should be getting the output you desire.

Comment: What you want is apparently a variable that can store the value -7.830 exactly. But this is not possible. In binary, you would need an infinite number of digits to store this number. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1679849)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to work..

`(Math.random() * 40 - 20).toFixed(3)` even like this

Working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgcLf6m/2/

Comment: but it generate value -7.829999999999999 actually, which I don't want to get.

Comment: Weird behaviour... Ok, lets try a different approach... 

'alert(Math.round((Math.random() * 40 - 20) * 1000) / 1000)'

Another working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgcLf6m/8/

Comment: tried, but it doesn't work, as it also generate -13.850000000000001

Answer (score 0):

Calling `parseFloat` on the end result should work.

`parseFloat((Math.random() * (40) -20).toFixed(3))`